# How to plot array topics on RQT_plot?

Tags: ros2, python, visualization, rqt-plot, array

I am working on a project where I need to plot data from **ROS2 array topics** using rqt_plot. The data I'm dealing with involves **multiple array topics**, which are **published per cycle** from another node. The structure of the ROS2 topics is as follows:

`float32[] range_m`

`float32[] velocity_mps`

`float32[] acceleration_mps2`

... (other similar array structures)

Each of these topics represents an array of values that I need to plot in each cycle. However, rqt_plot in its current form has limitations in plotting array topics, particularly when it comes to handling the entire array data for each cycle. It seems to only support plotting **specific indexed elements** of array topics.

I already attempted and did some research like, modifying rqt_plot for Array Topics:
I tried to modify rqt_plot to handle array topics by adjusting functions like _parse_field_name_and_index, get_plot_fields, and _ros_cb. The goal was to allow rqt_plot to interpret entire arrays as single plottable entities rather than requiring an index for each element.

Despite these efforts, I am still facing challenges in getting rqt_plot to correctly plot entire arrays per cycle. The main issues are ensuring data structure compatibility and correctly handling cycle-based data updates.

**Seeking Guidance:**
I am looking for suggestions or guidance on how to effectively modify rqt_plot for this purpose. Specifically, I need assistance with:

- Correctly modifying rqt_plot functions to handle entire array topics.
- Implementing an efficient and accurate cycle detection and plotting mechanism.
- Any known methods or best practices for handling similar scenarios in rqt_plot.

Any insights or advice from the community would be greatly appreciated, especially from those who have experience in modifying rqt_plot or dealing with similar ROS2 visualization challenges.

Comment: since you seem comfortable writing custom code to solve this problem, why not just write a node which 1. subscribes to the arrays then 2. re-shapes them to a format more useful to rqt_plot and 3. re-publishes them?

Comment: @cst0 to have something in between is always inefficient, in other words I could already publish the data in my main node in more friendly way with rqt_plot. However, the publish rate will be significantly higher, in my case it was around 150-170 Hz, this something I dont want. As I told in description, I attempted modifying rqt_plot to handle the entire list. I already managed, it is in testing phase, maybe I will create pull request after completion.